# Woocommerce order_id NULL

Tags: woocommerce

```
$subscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_all_users_subscriptions();
var_dump( $subscriptions );
```

results in:

```
...snip...

'2794_1425' => 
 array (size=15)
  'order_id' => null
  'product_id' => string '106' (length=3)
  'variation_id' => string '121' (length=3)
  'status' => string 'on-hold' (length=7)
  'period' => string 'month' (length=5)
  'interval' => string '1' (length=1)
  'length' => int 0
  'start_date' => string '2016-08-26 14:31:25' (length=19)
  'expiry_date' => int 0
  'end_date' => int 0
  'trial_expiry_date' => int 0
  'failed_payments' => string '' (length=0)
  'completed_payments' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '2016-08-26 14:52:47' (length=19)
  'suspension_count' => string '1' (length=1)
  'last_payment_date' => string '2016-09-27 14:28:38' (length=19)

  ...snip...
```

How can order_id be NULL? I can see the order on the orders page and and it does have an id.

Comment: Oh yes this is very strange… I have test it on my side, with different order statuses, but I always get an order ID. In the first line of your code `'2794_1425' =>`, it seems that the first part of this reference before `_` character matches with the order ID (in my case). So your Order ID should to be **`2794`**. That is the only thing that I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh,I took a look at the `WC_Subscriptions_Manager` class.

```
public static function get_all_users_subscriptions() {
    _deprecated_function( __METHOD__, '2.0' );

    foreach ( get_users() as $user ) {
        foreach ( wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user->ID ) as $subscription ) {
            $subscriptions_in_old_format[ wcs_get_old_subscription_key( $subscription ) ] = wcs_get_subscription_in_deprecated_structure( $subscription );
        }
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_all_users_subscriptions', $subscriptions_in_old_format );
}
```

`wcs_get_subscription_in_deprecated_structure( $subscription )` gets the subscription in a deprecated structure. Didn't keep looking at that point. Instead, got all the subscriptions like so:

```
    $subscriptions = array();

    foreach ( get_users() as $user ) {
        if ( count( wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user->ID ) ) ) {
            $subscriptions[] = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user->ID );
        }
    }

    // return false if there are no subscriptions
    $return = count( $subscriptions ) ? array_values( $subscriptions ) : false;
```